# ember-simple-auth: Persisting session in localstorage using custom authenticator

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

Setup:

- Ember             : 2.0.2
- Ember Data        : 2.0.1
- jQuery            : 1.11.3
- Ember Simple Auth : 1.0.0 (jjAbrams Branch)
- Ember CLI         : 1.13.8

I'm using pretender to mock a server.

Usecase:

Using a custom authenticator to interface with the server.

Have 2 routes: login, protected (and by default index,application)

When I login with the right credentials, the authenticate method of the authenticator gets called and successfully logs the response object which is passed to resolve().

Observations:

1. After logging in and being directed to the protected  page, Refreshing the protected route (Which has `AuthenticatedRouteMixin`) leads back to login page.
2. Localstorage has no values bound to it even after successful login.
   Before login: `ember_simple_auth:session -> {"authenticated":{}}`
3. `restore()` method of authenticator never called.
4. Going to another route from the protected route after auth and coming back goest to login page again.

```js
//authenticators/custom.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base';


export default Base.extend({
  restore: function (data) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      console.log("RESOLVE",data);
      if (!Ember.isEmpty(data.token)) {
        //TODO Remove log

        resolve(data);
      } else {
        console.log("REJECTING",data);
        reject();
      }
    });
  },
  authenticate(credentials) {
    
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: '/token',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
          email: credentials.identification,
          password: credentials.password
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
      }).then(function (response) {
        Ember.run(function () {
          //This logs the expected information
          console.log("Response", response, response.token, response.user);
          resolve(response);
        });
      }, function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("error", error, xhr.responseText);
        var response = xhr.responseText;
        Ember.run(function () {
          reject(response);
        });
      }));
  },

  invalidate(token) {
    return API.logout(token);
  }
});
```

```js
//environment.js
ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
  store: 'session-store:local-storage',
  routeAfterAuthentication: '/protected'
};
```

**TLDR;**
How do I make the session persist?

Comment: Are you actually using the most recent commit from the `jj-abrams` branch?

Comment: Presumably.. I cleared the old ESA deps from bower.json and package.json, Added the jjAbrams dep and ran npm and bower install as specified [here](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/pull/602)..

Comment: what's the content of local storage after you login and before the reload?

Comment: ember_simple_auth:session -> {"secure":{}} (before reload). I started a new project from scratch and pulled in each file from the old one at a time.It seems to be working fine now ( except, session.invalidate() throws some unknown error but that's for another question)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it all working together finally. Ember 2.0 and ESA 1.0

Here are the steps I took:

1. Create a new ember cli project
2. Update Ember and ember data values to ^2.0.0 in bower.json [Source](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/getting-started-with-ember-js-2-0-using-ember-cli.html)
3. Add ESA jjAbrams dep to package.json [Source](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/pull/602)
4. run npm install && bower install

Gotchas: (This was the original problem which caused the problems described in the question)

1. If you're upgrading from older versions of ESA, all references to 'simple-auth/..' should be updated to refer 'ember-simple-auth/..' instead..
   .. This include imports for authenticators, authorizers, stores, mixins and the Config key in the config/environment.js file.

All this shouldn't be an issue once ESA 1.0 and Ember Cli for Ember 2.0 comes out :)